# Media query support in older mobile browsers is sketchy what can I do about it?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

So I just found out that media queries are not supported in a large percentage of older mobile browsers. (source: book implementing responsive design). For instance the book says that 92% of Android users are browsing using Android v2.3 or earlier.. The current version is v4.x.

So I'm curious how to optimize for those users. Say I put the `<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width” />` in the head, since those browsers don't understand the following media queries, wouldn't they then just display a small fraction of the "desktop" layout (say 200px of the default 960px layout?)..

So I'm wondering if there would be anyway to remove the viewport metatag if the device doesn't support media queries so they can at least have the default desktop experience in those older browsers, any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is out dated, [see this chart here](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) for more up to date information.

To sum up quickly though 5.5% of android users are browsing with something less then 2.3 (5.6% if you count the first patch of 2.3).

After the patch in 2.3 the browser on those phones is really pretty decent, I would target that and above since this will cover 94.4% of all Android phone users.

Also if you [check this chart here](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries) you will see that support for actual css media queries goes all the way back to the android browser 2.1. (which means that 99.9% of users on android can see basic media queries)

Also if you look at these reports:

- [Browser 2.2 isn't seeing media queries](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11961)
- [Browser 2.3 isn't seeing my width media query](https://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/21625/solved-android-2-3-device-not-recognizing-media-queries/p1)

You will see that at least back to 2.2 the meta tag you specify `<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width” />` is supported (I would assume since media queries are supported in 2.1 the meta tag is as well, even if it isn't you still cover 98.2% of users).

If you really want to go though the effort for those last few percentage points you can use some javascript to detect if media queries are supported. Personally I would checkout a library like [modernizer](http://modernizr.com/). It will make your life much simpler if you choose to go that route.

Comment: Ryan, thanks for that chart.. I do find it a bit weird on the author of the book's part though, but maybe he wrote it in 2012 and things have changed a lot since.. He also mentions older blackberry's not supporting them either, but they may be an insignificant number now as well.

Comment: @MattD.  Books on programming are notorious for being out of date very quickly. And when it comes to the mobile market it's even worse. 18 months ago what your book says about %'s would of been true. As is he is still off on what versions support media queries. With something that moves as fast as mobile tech does the internet is your very best resource.

Comment: @MattD. Yep, not a problem. Sorry your books out of date, hopefully it didn't cost you much?

Comment: not a whole lot. Still a good deal of valuable info in there though. ;)

Comment: the book author recomends a mobile first approach as the solution to that issue. I'm not really sold on mobile first, since I think the core experience is on the desktop, but that's another discussion.

Comment: @MattD. well you also have the issue of new mobile phones, the S4 and HTC One, have 1080p resolutions, if I look at the desktop layout for sites on those I can see the entire thing, and even interact with it on a fairly user friendly basis.

Comment: interesting, so what do you recommend serving up for those users?

Comment: although I would guess the ability of media queries to detect those users is limited.